# Convert multiples images into its negative with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to read all the images in a folder and convert them into negatives of the same image

```
# Import library to work with Images
from PIL import Image

# Make negative pixel
def negatePixel(pixel):
    return tuple([255-x for x in pixel])

#img_dir = "" # Enter Directory of all images 

for i in range(1,130):
    # Original Image
    img = []
    img = Image.open(str(i) + '.jpg')
    # New clear image
    new_img = Image.new('RGB', img.size)

    # Get pixels from Image
    data = img.getdata()
    # Create map object consists of negative pixels
    new_data = map(negatePixel, data)

    # Put negative pixels into the new image
    new_img.putdata(list(new_data))
    # Save negative Image
    new_img.save(str(i) + 'neg.jpg')

    print ('saved image' + str(i))
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_img.putdata(list(new_data))
  File "2.py", line 6, in negatePixel
    return tuple([255-x for x in pixel])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I wrote the above programme to perform what I wanted it to, but it is striking an error. I'm new to programming and is there any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the stated issue for RGB images, but for grayscale (single channel) images. Can you confirm that behavior? Inside your `negatePixel(pixel)` method, check for `if isinstance(pixel, tuple)`. If `True`, do what you're currently doing, but if `False`, just `return 255-pixel`. That worked for me when passing a grayscale image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is not ideal. Firstly, you can do that much more simply with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Just in Terminal, this will invert all files in the current directory:

```
magick mogrify -negate *.jpg
```

Or, if you want them saved in a directory called `results`:

```
mkdir results
magick mogrify -path results -negate *.jpg
```

---

If you want to stick to Python and PIL/Pillow, there is already a `invert()` function in its `ImageOps` module [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.invert):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Load image 
im = Image.open('image.jpg')

# Invert
result = ImageOps.invert(im)

# Save
result.save('result.jpg')
```

---

If you don't want to use the built-in `invert()`, you will be much better off using the `point()` function [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#point-operations):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image 
im = Image.open('image.jpg')

# Negate
result = im.point(lambda p: 255 -p)

# Save
result.save('result.jpg')
```

**Note**: In general, as soon as you start using a `for` loop, or `getdata()` with an image in Python, you have probably already gone wrong. You should use built-in library functions or Numpy really, else everything will be slo-o-o-o-o-o-w.